# Draw overbrace from one superscript to other

Tags: superscripts, overbrace

I would like to draw overlapping braces from exponent to exponent.

For example, I'd like to connect v and w, and x and y

a<sup>v</sup>b<sup>x</sup>c<sup>w</sup>d<sup>y</sup>

with an overbrace each. So it should kinda look like this
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not finding the result very pretty:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\[
\ooalign{%
  \phantom{$a\,$}$\overbrace{\phantom{\!{}^vb^xc^w\!}}\phantom{\,d^y}$\cr
  \noalign{\kern2pt}
  \phantom{$a^vb\,$}$\overbrace{\phantom{\!{}^xc^wd^y\!}}\,$\cr
  $a^vb^xc^wd^y$\cr
}
\]

\[
\ooalign{%
  \phantom{$a\,$}$\overbrace{\phantom{\!{}^vb^xc^w\!}}\phantom{\,d^y}$\cr
  $a^vb^xc^wd^y$\cr
  \phantom{$a^vb\,$}$\underbrace{\phantom{\!{}^xc^wd^y\!}}\,$\cr
}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Probably `\overbracket` from `mathtools` would look a bit nicer.

Comment: Indeed yes. But perhaps with a little opacity it could make the output better. Anyway +1 for the question and for the answer.